# Haskell IF statements

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new to haskell, but if you make an if statement:

```
function a b c
     | (a+b == 0) = True
     | --etc.
     | otherwise = False
```

Is the second if statement the same as an else if in other languages, or is it just another if.  I assume its the former as you can only have one output, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, your line of reasoning was on the right track.  What would it mean to have more than one right side "executed"? There are no side effects so everything we "do" we must return. Which value would we return?  Or we would have to have a way to combine them... which way would we use?  (Just a few questions to guide you to Haskell philosophy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The construct you used is called a **guard**. Haskell checks the given alternatives one after another until one condition yields `True`. It then evaluates the right hand side of that equation.

You could pretty well write

```
function n 
   | n == 1 = ...
   | n == 2 = ...
   | n >= 3 = ...
```

thus the guard kinds of represents an if/elseif construct from other languages. As `otherwise` is simply defined as `True`, the last

```
| otherwise =
```

will always be true and therefore represents a catch-all `else` clause.

Nontheless, Haskell has a usual `a = if foo then 23 else 42` statement.

Comment: Note that in Haskell, the `else` portion of `if` statements is mandatory. See [Haskell 2010: Conditionals](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-320003.6). And then there's ["when" and "unless"](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:when)

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is not really an if statement, but rather a guard. But you are right that the second case gets "executed" only if the previous cases (by cases here I mean the expressions between the `|` and `=`) did not match (evaluate to `True`). `otherwise` is just a synonyme to `True` (that way it always "matches").

Answer (score 1):

It must be like an else if.

The bottom pattern `otherwise` is really just `True`, so if the first match didn't win, you would always get the more specific value and the otherwise value.

Answer (score 1):

Correct.  Though you've used guards, the way you've expressed it is more or less identical to using an if-statement.  The flow of testing the conditional to yield a result will fall through the guard you've written in the order they were listed in your guard.

```
(a+b == 0)
```

Will be checked first

```
etc.
```

Will be checked second and so forth, provided no preceding conditional is true.

```
otherwise
```

Will be checked last, provided no preceding conditional is true.